# Converting Powershell script to jenkins job

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have the following function:

```
function DivideAndCreateFiles ([string] $file, [string] $ruleName) {
    $Suffix = 0
    $FullData = Get-Content $file
    $MaxIP = 40
        
    while ($FullData.count -gt 0 ){
        $NewData = $FullData | Select-Object -First $MaxIP
        $FullData = $FullData | Select-Object -Skip $MaxIP
        $NewName = "$ruleName$Suffix"
        New-Variable -name $NewName -Value $NewData
        Get-Variable -name $NewName -ValueOnly  | out-file "$NewName.txt" 
        $Suffix++
    }
   
}
```

This function takes a file location, this file holds hundreds of ips. It then iterate the file and create files from it each one holding 40 IP's naming it $rulename$suffix so if $rulename=blabla

I would get blabla_0, blabla_1, and so on, each with 40 ips.

I need to convert this logic and put it inside a jenkins job.
This file is in the working dir of the job and is called ips.txt

```
suffix = 0
maxIP = 40
ips = readFile('ips.txt')

...
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new variable in every iteration?

Comment: Im creating a variable to hold the new name and the data and then write it to a file

Comment: That's a mighty memory consuming way of doing that.. Have you seen the [-ReadCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) of `Get-Content`?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the PowerShell script? You could just call the existing script as a Jenkins step like `powershell '.\YourScript.ps1'` (for PS 5.x) and `pwsh '.\YourScript.ps1'` (for PS 7.x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using something like the following groovy code:

```groovy
def divideAndCreateFiles(path, rule_name, init_suffix = 0, max_ip = 40){
    // read the file and split lines by new line separator
    def ips = readFile(path).split("\n").trim()   
  
    // divide the IPs into groups according to the maximum ip range          
    def ip_groups = ips.collate(ips.size().intdiv(max_ip))   
 
    // Iterate over all groups and write them to the corresponding file
    ip_groups.eachWithIndex { group, index ->
        writeFile file : "${rule_name}${init_suffix + index}", text: group.join("\n")
    }
}
```

From my perspective, because you are already writing a full pipeline in groovy, it is easier to handle all logic in groovy, including this function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer about converting to Jenkins, but a re-write of your original PowerShell function, which splits a file in a very inefficient way.
(can't do that in a comment)

This utilizes the `-ReadCount` parameter of `Get-Content`, which specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time.

Also, I have renamed the function to comply to the [Verb-Noun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.2#verb-naming-recommendations) naming recommendations.

```
function Split-File ([string]$file, [string]$ruleName, [int]$maxLines = 40) {
    $suffix = 0
    $path   = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($file)
    Get-Content -Path $file -ReadCount $maxLines | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}.txt' -f $ruleName, $suffix++))
    }
}
```